# Silverlight/Windows Phone 7 Equivalent of android.os.Handler

Tags: android, windows-phone-7, message-queue

The Android platform has a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) class for queueing messages or events to be run at a later stage or on a different thread. I was looking around the MSDN docs and the net for some equivalent API available on the the Windows Phone 7 platform but did not find anything.

I could implement that service myself but would hate to reinvent the wheel. Has anyone had found something similar or have any bright ideas?

Cheers,
Alasdair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the gist of the code. You will definitely need to make changes. Hope it helps.

```
   private static Queue<Dictionary<string, string>> messages;
   ....
   {   
        ...
        AutoResetEvent ev = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        ...
        Dictionary<string, string> msg1 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        msg1.Add("Id", "1");
        msg1.Add("Fetch", "Song1");
        Dictionary<string, string> msg2 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        msg2.Add("Id", "2");
        msg2.Add("Fetch", "Song2");

        messages.Enqueue(msg1);
        messages.Enqueue(msg2);

        ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(
            ev,
            new WaitOrTimerCallback(WaitProc),
            messages,
            5000,
            false
        );

        // The main thread waits 10 seconds, to demonstrate the
        // time-outs on the queued thread, and then signals.
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        ...
    }
    private static void WaitProc(object state, bool timedOut)
    {
        // The state object must be cast to the correct type, because the
        // signature of the WaitOrTimerCallback delegate specifies type
        // Object.
        Queue<Dictionary<string, string>> dict = (Queue<Dictionary<string, string>>)state;

        string cause = "TIMED OUT";
        if (!timedOut)
        {
            cause = "SIGNALED";
            //signaled to return. return without doing any work
            return;
        } 
        // timed out. now do the work 
        Dictionary<string, string> s1 = dict.Dequeue();
    }
```

`

Comment: I don't it is necessary to provide a full code example to answer my question. Suggesting the ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject method call would have be sufficient. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @ajmccall, I must have misunderstood. Since I had mentioned `ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject` in my previous response, I thought you were looking for additional details. Anyway, glad that this helped.

Comment: I don't think this answer is thread-safe. The Queue object is being shared across threads, but the documentation indicates that instances of a Queue are not automatically thread safe: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue.aspx Also this implementation is a bit different from a Handler since in this case it keeps waiting 5 seconds over and over, a Handler is more flexible, it doesn't require every message to wait the exact same amount of time before being processed.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are looking for a service to execute something in the background or something on a thread. Have you looked at [ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) class for threading?

You can use [ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kbf0f1ct%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to run on a different thread or use ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject to register a delegate to wait for a timeout and run later.

Comment: Thanks @Vivek I am aware of those APIs and have been using them to implement the desired behaviour. The nice features about implementing using Handler is you get the queuing of the messages/actions for free, along with the ability to cancel the queue if necessary.

Comment: Okay, I understand. True, you get the ability to schedule and pass a message in case of Android. I am sure you have thought about it - to pass a queue of dictionary items in RegisterWaitForSingleObject. May be that could do something similar?

Comment: You will also want to look up Dispatcher.BeginInvoke to execute code back on the main thread (to show the results of your calculations, network call, etc).

Comment: yes thanks, that is exactly what I needed. I saw this API but couldn't read through the programming jargon to see what it really did. Please edit your answer and I'll mark it correct. Cheers